# Multiple ViewModels Knockout with JQuery

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I Have this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcus2/)

It is working perfectly in the fiddle, but as soon as i put everything in a ASP.NET MVC4 Application the second ViewModel is not loaded!
This normally is only when i add the following Script Tag to my Project

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Do i need some JQuery Functions to load the second ViewModel or what did i wrong? ;)

Here is my code:

```
<form action="" data-bind=" template:{ 'if': loginVM, data: loginVM }"> 
 //SomeCode
</form>

<form action="" data-bind=" template:{ 'if': startVM, data: startVM}"> 
//Some Code
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

        var masterViewModel = {

            loginVM: ko.observable(),
            startVM: ko.observable(),
            projektUnterbrechen: ko.observable(),
            logout : ko.observable(),
            projectStartVM: ko.observable()

        };

        var LoginVM = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.mandant = ko.observable();
            self.user = ko.observable();
            self.password = ko.observable();
            self.showDetails = function () {
                if ((self.user() == "Gregor") && (self.password() == "gregrech")) {
                    masterViewModel.loginVM(null);
                    masterViewModel.startVM(new StartVM());
                    **//alert(masterViewModel.startVM()!=null) //==True** 


                }
                else {
                    alert("Username oder Passwort falsch");
                }

            };
        };

        var StartVM = function () {
            self = this;
            **//alert(masterViewModel.startVM()!=null) //==False**
            //Um weiterzumachen muss man eingeloggt sein
            self.favoriten = ko.observableArray([
                {
                    projectName: "Favorit1"
                },
                {
                    projectName: "Favorit2"
                },
                {
                    projectName: "Favorit3"
                }
                ]);
            //Die zuletzt verwendeten Projekte
            self.zuletzt = ko.observableArray([
            {
                lastProjName: "Zuletzt1"
            },
            {
                lastProjName: "Zuletzt2"
            },
            {
                lastProjName: "Zuletzt3"
            }
            ]);
            self.showStart = function (projectName, data, event) {
                masterViewModel.projectStartVM(new ProjectStartVM(projectName));
                masterViewModel.startVM(null);
            };
        };
        masterViewModel.loginVM(new LoginVM());
        $(document).on('pageinit', function () {
            ko.applyBindings(masterViewModel);
        });

</script>
```

Thank you for your answers

EDIT:
I found out, that i get different Values if i compare my masterViewModel.startVM()!= null even if it has to be the same!
Maybe this helps you!
Please look at the comments with "**" in my Code to understand what i mean

Comment: When you put it into an MVC app and it is not working what do you seen in your browser's javascript console? Are there any errors?

Comment: I now found a little thing out. Maybe you could see now what i did wrong

Comment: this is old, just curious, if you solved this.

Comment: The Problem was solved and i found out that JQuery was a wrong thing to use here.
Knockout itself was just fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to load viewmodel in ready event not pageinit event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(masterViewModel);
});
```

Comment: that didn't help!

The problem is, that the second ViewModel is executed, but it seems like the 'if' binding breaks with JQery, what is really strange

Comment: I Editet my Question. 
Maybe you could take a look on it again?

Comment: How about applying startvm viewmodel when it is instantiated rather than applying initial time.

Comment: that's not the problem... 
I found out that it has to do with JQuery Mobile, which somehow stops updating the viewmodel
I'm trying to find a soloution to this
But thank you for your answer